# Google Api Calendar and Spring Boot not working because of dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use the Google Api for Calendar (https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) but, when I include the dependencies in my spring boot project I get an error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

It looks like it is related to the fact that google api uses Jetty.
These are my build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0"
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0'

    compile 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'

    gradleLint.ignore('unused-dependency') {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you start the server without the Google dependencies? This seems like an error that occurs when your runtime environment Java version (Elipse's JRE/JDK) and the Tomcat version mismatch.

Comment: I can. If I add the dependencies, then it does not.